# What grok pattern i can use for non ISO8601 format

Tags: elasticsearch, date-format, logstash-grok, filebeat, grok

What grok pattern i can use to reflect data on Elastic MARS dashboard for the following timestamp:

```
2019-05-14 - 00:00:11.574
```

I tried the pattern `%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}` but it didn't work.

Comment: Try this `%{DATE:date} \- %{TIME:time}`

Comment: https://grokdebugger.com/ Is an amazing tool to use to help demonstrate what you want to do and how things works. @Sourav has shown how to Grok the date and time into 2 separate fields. But if you want them in a different format in 1 field, something else might be an option.

Comment: @Sourav care to post an answer based on your comment?